# How do I include a related object when serving JSON in Spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have this basic controller method:

```
@GetMapping
List<Employee> all() {
    return employeeRepository.findAll();
}
```

By default, it seems to serve the JSON representation of `Employee` just fine, except there's one problem: there's no associated `Department` in the JSON output.

I've googled and googled and googled, and I can't seem to find an answer.

Employee:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String emailAddress;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    private Department department;

    private String phoneNumber;
}
```

Department

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Department {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="department")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Employee> employees;
}
```

Comment: if you add ``@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)`` in employee class, it should fetch the associated ``department`` object along with ``employee``.

Comment: Wow, ok haha, I thought it was eager by default, but I guess that's for JPA? Apparently Hibernate is all lazy by default. Thank you!

Comment: So I specified `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` on the `@ManyToOne` on `Employee`, but I'm still not seeing the `Department` being included in the `Employee` JSON.

Comment: I can see it in the IntelliJ debugger, when I look at the `List<Employee>` result from `employeeRepository`, it includes a `department`, but this is not appearing in the JSON output.

Comment: @JsonBackReference is not allowing your data in the response

Comment: @GnanaJeyam hm ok, I thought it was needed to prevent infinite loops when serializing as JSON

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probably the mix with JPA.
As you are already using Lombok (@Getter, @Setter).

You can do this:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Employee {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String emailAddress;
    private Department department;
    private String phoneNumber;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Department {
   ...
}
```